# How to easilly get the name of the admin which created an item in the template

Tags: django, admin

Is there an easy way to reference the creator (admin)'s name of an item from within a template.

If not, what is the easiest method of passing the value through from the view?

Comment: You can pass anything you like to the template as context but then again it all depends pretty much on your concrete models and views. 
You should show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Add a foreign key to the user model** e.g.: `creator = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True)`
2. **Overload [modeladmin.save_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods)** method to set obj.creator to request.user as in the documentation
3. **Access youritem.creator** in the template e.g.: `{{ item.creator }}`

Comment: @TonyBlundell: Except you left out the most important part: overriding `save_model` so that the user is actually stored when the object is created. Otherwise, you just have an empty field.

Comment: Suppose I could have given an example of that.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't store the creator automatically, you'll need to add a field to your model and store it yourself when you create the object.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # stuff
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then in your template, you can access it like this...

```
{{ my_object.creator }}
```

Comment: Thanks- just checking there wasn't any in built functionality for it.